# Open GL ES - texture with alpha clears background

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm writing an android game with open gl es 1.0 using the framework taken from "beginning android games".

I'm trying to draw some lines using a line strip, followed by a textured polygon.

But what's happening is, when I draw the texture, it blanks out the lines that were drawn first, even though they are nowhere near the textured block.

After banging my head against it for a long time, I've discovered that if I switch to an image without an alpha channel, it works and doesn't clear the background. But if I go back to my image with a transparent background, the problem occurs.

Here is a picture with some screenshots: http://imgbox.com/abxDKzSd
The one at the top shows the screen using image without alpha, the one below is exactly the same but the image has transparency.

- I see the lines flash up very briefly when the activity starts, but never after that
- I'm enabling blending
- My texture dimensions are powers of 2 (128 x 32)
- I'm checked for gl errors after every call and don't see any
- I'm running it directly on my kindle fire HD, the emulator doesn't appear to work with this at all.

Here is a snippet of the code where I'm rendering my primitives, followed by my textured block:

```
GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

m_guiCam.setViewportAndMatrices();

// draw the lines
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glLineWidth(15.0f);

m_vertices.position(0);
gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_SIZE, m_vertices);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, m_numVerts);

// draw textures
m_guiCam.setViewportAndMatrices();
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

m_batcher.beginBatch(Assets.mfTex);
TextureRegion keyFrame = Assets.mfAnim.getKeyFrame(0.0f, Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
m_batcher.drawSprite(250, 250, 32, 32, keyFrame);
m_batcher.endBatch();

gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

I've made the smallest example I can manage which still exhibits the problem, and it's available here: https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0Bz7e5tdnz97Id21XZkJoQ005NlU/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me figure out why it's doing this? I just can't get it to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! Finally figured it out

Turns out I had to move the

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

call down to *after* where I was rendering my lines. I put it just after enabling the blending.
I also had to disable the texturing after I drew my textured sprite. Because otherwise texturing would still be enabled when it comes back round to render my lines again on the next frame.

So something about enabling textures was enough to disrupt the line drawing.
Obtuse!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable `GL_DEPTH_TEST` otherwise if you draw something at a higher/equal depth than something that already exists, it will not show up.

So in your case, add `gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST)` where you enable blending (and enable it again when you don't blend).
You will probably also want to clear the depth buffer at the beginning of your drawing: `gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
It's still not working unfortunately.
It sounds like the right kind of answer, but I'm not sure how it explains the texture without the alpha working ok?